# Handler for file names

Tags: c#, filesystems, .net

When windows is displaying the files through Window Explorer I need to have the ability to change the icon of the file type before it is displayed.  I have seen application like SubVersion and Carbonite, change the icons depending on their status, but how do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That requires a "shell extension", in particular an "icon overlay handler"; I haven't done it myself, but perhaps search on those terms, or look at [this discussion](http://www.mombu.com/programming/c/t-c-shell-extension-handler-icon-overlay-handler-1568092.html).

Comment: Yes that would work  :-)

Also found

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/overlayicon.aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144123(VS.85).aspx